# Show select box options dependant on a quantity

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating a booking page where there will be a quantity remaining select box. The initial value will be 6, if someone books 2 tickets then I want the next visitor to only be able to select a quantity from 1 to 4.

I am guessing I would use a PHP array where I take the variable 4 and only generate option tags from 1 to 4.

I have no idea how to do this as a newbie. Can anyone help?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

```
<?php
   $val = "4";
   
   ?>
<form>
   <select>
      <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
      <?php
         foreach (range(1, $val) as $number) {
             echo "<option value='".$number."'>".$number."</option>";
         }
                 ?>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```